# Как заменить три первых символа на звездочки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как зашифровать электронные почты, к примеру исходник `liza491@mail.ru` Хочу шифровать первые 3 символа результат: `***a491@mail.ru`
Делаю так, `.replace(/[aA-zZ]{3}/g, '*')` но, результат получается совсем другим.

Comment: Почему требуются именно регулярные выражения? Простая замена первых трёх символов не подходит? Вроде этого: `'***' + 'liza491@mail.ru'.substr(3)`

Comment: @PavelGrishaev спасибо, подойдет) Просто намучался с регуляркой, не могу понять как сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно делать так:
`'***' + 'liza491@mail.ru'.substring(3)`

Или регулярными:

```
'liza491@mail.ru'.replace(/([\w]|.){3}/, '***')
```

Comment: добавил вариант с регуляркой)

Comment: большое спасибо) Моя ошибка в том, что я ставил одну звездочку)) Думал она заменит 3 раза)

Comment: не только, флаг g лишний

Comment: А, хотя да)) точно)

Comment: вариант с регуляркой следует начинать корректно с `^`, если хочется  замену в начале строки сделать

Comment: это не обязательно, потому что все символы, которые допустимы в синтаксисе email прописаны в флаге \w - буквы, символы. Единственное, заметил, что не хватает точки, ну а флаг \s лишний, т.к. пробелы не допускаются) Поправил ответ